# How to compute the terms in a recurrence equation

Tags: list-manipulation, table

I have a recurrence equation:

a[k_, m_] := Sum[Binomial[k + m, k] *(2^k - 1)^s* 2 (k (m - s))* a[s, m - s], {s, 1, m}]

The initial conditions are that a[k,0]=1 for every k>=0.

How do I get a table of values for the first few terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

a[k_Integer?NonNegative, 0] := 1

a[k_Integer?NonNegative, m_Integer?NonNegative] :=
 a[k, m] = 
  Sum[Binomial[k + m, k] (2^k - 1)^s 2^(k (m - s))*a[s, m - s], 
   {s, 1, m}]

kmax = 4; mmax = 3;

Table[a[k, m], {k, 0, kmax}, {m, 0, mmax}] // 
 TableForm[#, TableHeadings ->
    {Range[0, kmax], Range[0, mmax]}] &
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  By the way I had a typo in the code:  the factor 2 (k (m - s))  should be 2^(k (m - s)) which gives the number of labeled acyclic graphs classified by number of outpoints.